# Difference between "höhnen" and "verhöhnen" as well as "spotten" and "verspotten"

Tags: meaning, difference, verb, vocabulary

What is exactly the difference between *höhnen* and *verhöhnen*, and also between *spotten* and *verspotten*? The differentiation in dictionaries is not clear, but I assume they are not the same thing in practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *ver-* variants are transitive:

1. Er spottete über das neue Produkt.
2. Er verspottete seinen Chef.

The transitive version feels more "personal", you'd probably use 1. for things (or maybe talking badly about someone behind their back), and 2. for people that are present. But that's just my feeling as a native speaker.

I'm not sure if I've heard *höhnen* (without *ver*) before.

Comment: "höhnen" is a valid word and it is used, albeit the rarest of the four: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=höhnen%2Cverhöhnen%2Cspotten%2Cverspotten&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chöhnen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cverhöhnen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspotten%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cverspotten%3B%2Cc0

Comment: The verb “höhnen” is usually found in written language, where it may serve as a more expressive alternative to more general or bland verbs like “sagen”, “rufen” or “schreien”. An example sentence could be: „‚Da kann ja meine Oma noch besser kämpfen!‘ höhnte er und ging zum Angriff über.“

Comment: It's wrth noting that "spotten" can be used with Genitive as well... Ich spotte seiner. Das spottet jeder Beschreibung.

Comment: Though “spotten” may carry a (sometimes positive) notion of teasing, whereas I can’t think of “höhnen” as not being malicious.